# What is the clang analogue of ldd?

Tags: clang, ldd

How do I find out what DLLs an executable depends on?

On systems with the GNU development toolchain (`gcc` &c) I use `ldd` for that, but what about the `clang` systems, like, e.g., Mac OS X (which does *not* have `ldd`)?

Comment: Have you tried `ldd` ? The OS must be able to figure out the libraries needed, so `clang` and `gcc` mustdo pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @MSalters: macosx does not have `ldd`

Comment: Eh, it's apparently `otool -L`. The point I failed to make was that the compiler doesn't matter (there's a gcc port for MacOSX)

Comment: @MSalters: please turn your comment into an answer so that I can accept it and close the question. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Mac OSX, you'd use `otool -L` instead of `ldd`. This works regardless of the compiler you used. Other operating systems may have yet other tools; e.g. on Windows you'd use `Dependency Walker`.

Comment: Also, for inspecting Linux binaries on a macOS, `greadelf` from MacPorts can be used, as well as `nm`: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/418357/43390, also relevant to: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45464584/1959808. When trying `otool -L` for a Linux executable, an error was raised "object is not a Mach-O file type.".

Answer (score 7):

`llvm-readelf ---needed-libs`  is the clang analogue of ldd. Here's is the  [official documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/CommandGuide/llvm-readelf.html#cmdoption-llvm-readelf-needed-libs)

```
~/weechat $ llvm-readelf --needed-libs bin/weechat
NeededLibraries [
  libc.so
  libcurl.so
  libdl.so
  libgcrypt.so
  libgnutls.so
  libgpg-error.so
  libiconv.so
  libm.so
  libncursesw.so.6
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).