# How to check what binary library file does python link to?

Tags: python, libraries, dynet

Some time ago, I [installed dynet for Python](http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html) and it worked fine. I installed it automatically with `pip install git+https://github.com/clab/dynet#egg=dynet`.

Then, I wanted to add MKL support. So I installed dynet again manually,  using the instructions here: http://dynet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python.html#manual-installation, passing a `-DMKL` parameter to cmake.

I want to make sure that I did everything correctly and that Python indeed takes the new installation of dynet. How can I check this?

In general, when I have a library that is built in C++ and linked from Python, how can I check, from within Python, the details of the installed library, and particularly, what binary file does Python link to?

Comment: *How* did you install dynet? Using the system package manager, pip, directly from source?

Comment: I see the library has a `__version__` attribute; `import dynet; print(dynet.__version__)`.

Comment: The library would have to expose, in some library-specific manner, what flags were used to build it. There is no standard for that. Python stores such metadata in the `sys` and [`sysconfig`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html) modules, but that doesn't cover extension modules.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I added explanation. Initially I installed automatically using pip, but later I wanted to add a flag so I installed manually from source.  __version__ only gives the major version number (2.0), it gives no details about flags..

Comment: @MartijnPieters Is there a way to see what binary file does python link to? Then, I can see whether the binary file is the one I just re-built.

Comment: Looking at the source the extension module is imported as `_dynet`, so `import _dynet; print(_dynet.__file__)`, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters great, this solved my problem! Where in the source did you find it?

Comment: I found the [`dynet.py.in` file](https://github.com/clab/dynet/blob/master/python/dynet.py.in) on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is tricky. There is no standard way, you have to rely on information provided by the package (which many don't do) and on implementation details for the specific library.

Python libraries *often* expose their version number in a `__version__` attribute. This attribute is *not standardised*, it is at most a convention. The `dynet` library does have this attribute but it doesn't list the patch-level version, only the major and minor versions:

```
>>> import dynet
>>> dynet.__version__
'2.0'
```

Because you installed the library either directly from the version control system (with `git+https://...`) or manually from source, you can't use `pip freeze` or `pkg_resources.get_distribution()` to inspect the version either:

```
$ pip freeze | grep -i dynet
dyNET==0.0.0
```

Compilation flags are **not stored anywhere**, normally. Python exposes it's own compilation-time info in structures in the [`sys` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) and the [`sysconfig` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sysconfig.html), but there is no such facility for extension modules. Unless the extension module explicitly includes such info in the API, you are out of luck there.

At best, you can try to locate the actual dynamic module loaded. Many projects use a *wrapper Python module*, which indirectly loads the actual extension module, confusing matters. In this case, importing `dynet` gives you the `dynet.py` file:

```
>>> dynet.__file__
'/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/dynet.py'
```

This file was generated from the [`dynet.py.in` file](https://github.com/clab/dynet/blob/master/python/dynet.py.in) in the project source code. It imports the dynamic module as `_dynet`:

```
from _dynet import *
```

So you can still at least find the *location* of the dynamic object loaded with:

```
>>> import _dynet
>>> _dynet.__file__
'/.../lib/python3.6/site-packages/_dynet.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
```

You can further check what that dynamic library links to if you want to check they are the right versions; how you do this is platform dependent:

- On most UNIX system's you'd use `ldd`, see [How to show all shared libraries used by executables in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50159/how-to-show-all-shared-libraries-used-by-executables-in-linux)
- On OS X, use `otool -L` instead, see [What is the clang analogue of ldd?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23697641/what-is-the-clang-analogue-of-ldd)
- On Windows, you need a third-party tool like dependency walker or the VS `dumpbin` tool, see [How to check for DLL dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378959/how-to-check-for-dll-dependency)

Comment: @ErelSegalHalevi: sorry, I had to roll back that edit. `ldd` is not a tool available on OS X, but you edited in my OS X path into the answer; you'd use `otool -L` instead. For Windows, you'd have to use a different tool altogether again. I'll happily link to instructions on how to list what dependencies are there on different platforms, but to put all that into this one probably is a little too verbose.

Answer (score 1):

3 ways from [this source](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/python-ways-check-version-installed-rishikesh-agrawani/):

```
>>> import django
>>> django.__version__
'1.8'
>>> 
>>> import flask
>>> flask.__version__
'0.11.1'
>>> 
>>> import urllib2
>>> urllib2.__version__
'2.7'
>>> 
>>> import json
>>> json.__version__
'2.0.9'
```

Or by using `pkg_resources`

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('flask').version
```

Or by using `pip freeze`

`pip freeze | find /I "virtualenv"`

Comment: While `__version__` is more widespread, it is **still package specific**. If a package doesn't set it, it is not set.

Comment: There won't be a perfect solution for it if author just didn't give any information about version. For example, as Martijn Pieters♦ has metioned, no `__version__` is set.

Comment: These methods only give serial version number, but do not give information about flags used during the build.  Is there maybe a way to see what binary file does python link to?

Comment: The version is either `2.0` or `0.0.0` according to each of these methods. All those are *wrong*.

Answer (score 0):

Not very clear with your question.
But you can see all installed libraries by running the below command.

```
pip freeze
```

It will list all the libraries installed in your environment along with its version number.

Comment: It won't list the version number for packages installed directly from github, as the OP has done.